# Using ES6 Template Literals in nodeJs v4.4.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I need to use ES6 Template Literals in Node v4.4.2.

After setting `jsconfig.json` I am not able to create my string properly.

Any idea what am I missing here?

```
var name = "Juan",
    job = "flying penguin";
var sentence = 'Hello${name},the ${job}!';
console.log(sentence);
```

------------- jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you need to use ` instead of ' . moreover you need to write `${name}` (no spaces).

Comment: You have to use no spaces: { name } insteo of {name}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

2 Things:

1. ` instead of '
2. No spaces after `$`

Something like this:

```
var name = "Juan",
    job = "flying penguin";
var sentence = `Hello ${name},the ${job}!`;
console.log(sentence);
```

Comment: Just a curiosity, when using VS 2015 Community and typing ` instead of ' IDE gets a syntax error. Any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: @GibboK sorry, I have no experience with VS 2015