# Triggering Google Cloud function using console

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use the google cloud console to test a cloud function. Below is a snippet.

```
exports.requestCreated = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/requests/{requestId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
    // execute operation
    });
```

I have tried all sorts of combination of JSON data. E.g.

```
{"userId":"Xl86pqOpF9T2MAn12p24OJAfYJW2","requestId":"abc1234"}
```

But I keep getting the following statement in logs:

```
Request created by {userId}
```

The actual `userId` is not being read from the JSON data in the console. Can you help?

Comment: where is `userId` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the execution of the cloud function. It's a problem with hardcoding the string.

`'users/{userId}/requests/{requestId}'` is a hardcoded string. Node.js will not automatically replace `{userId}` with the value of the variable `userId`.

Following [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600095/4402434), try something like this using **template strings**:

```
`users/${userId}/requests/${requestId}`
```

Please note it is surrounded by backticks (`), not single quotes (').

This assumes you already have a `userId` and `requestId` variables defined. You must restructure your cloud function [like this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/direct#cloud_pubsub_example) to retrieve that data. Notice that the specific variable values must be extracted from the `event` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Nareddyt. The function is for Firestore, and the way it is written right now checks if a new document is created under the collection requests. I tried replacing the string as you suggested, but as you pointed out, it requires these variables to be defined. I do not quite understand how to restructure the cloud function because the syntax I have used is how event detection is suggested in the Firestore documentation. My function currently works in its entirety, but testing it is a major pain. I have to go through my mobile app and do the whole userflow to test this function. I am new to Node.js and any guidance would be appreciated.